# Language util name byte counting

Tags: discussion, code-golf, scoring

I'm trying to figure out how the byte counting works in ["*Sum the numbers on standard in*"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/113674/sum-the-numbers-on-standard-in/113709#113709).  In [one answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/113709/53016) using the `jq` util counts the non-space bytes *after* the util name, but not the util or the spaces.  Using similar reckoning, (i.e. don't count the util name), one could get a byte count of **0** from [`numsum`](http://suso.suso.org/programs/num-utils/).

Possibly the distinction is between programs which are also languages, (i.e. `jq` describes itself as a *language*, therefore *don't* count the language binary name), and utils that are not, (so *do* count the util name).  If so, perhaps the question is what distinguishes a language from a util with a lot of switches.

Supposing a clear distinction exists between language executables and utils, there's then the question as to language executables used as utils, as in [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/113683/53016) where the pipe `|bc` is counted even though `bc` describes itself as a language.

Comment: The program "add" is being run with the flag -s. They are simply giving instructions as to how to run this from terminal. The way you are saying it should be scored would be if it was submitted as bash + utils

Comment: @fəˈnɛtɪk, If `add` is a `jq` program, then explain why `+` is not a `bc` program.  To simplify, assume the input to stdin is strictly two numbers.

Comment: I don't know if + is a bc program. However, if it only adds 2 numbers it does not fit the IO requirements of that problem

Comment: @fəˈnɛtɪk, Re "*the IO requirements*": the "*Sum the number...*" OP states that "*The input will contain at least one integer.*"

Comment: And + would fail for over 2 integers. Which is included in the requirements for that challenge.

Comment: @fəˈnɛtɪk, Please suppose that OP said "*the input will contain exactly two numbers*" -- all of that Q's answers, and the SECG counting rules, would still apply.

Comment: @agc: In that case, `+` would be a perfectly valid answer. When a challenge is very easy (such as adding two numbers), it will often have a very short answer in many languages; that's not really a problem (except possibly with the challenge itself).

Comment: @ais523, Please note this thread is about whether or not to count `|bc` as three bytes.  It's not about what's passed to `|bc`.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, the rule is that the name of an executable counts if you have to access that executable *during the course of running the code*, rather than it being the thing that runs the code in of itself. In the example of the bash + bc answer, `bc` is counted as 2 bytes because those two characters are part of the *Bash* program (it needs them to figure out that it has to call into bc rather than some other executable), rather than anything to do with bc itself. `bash` isn't counted, even though you'd likely need to type it to run the program, because the program's a Bash program.

The general rule is that you take the shortest method of running a program in your language as "+0" bytes of penalties. Anything you need to do to the command line beyond that gives you byte penalties.

For what it's worth, I believe this challenge has a valid 0-byte answer () in numsum, and a valid 6-byte answer (`numsum`) in Bash + numsum. (Note how those are different languages. The former isn't a programming language; atm we don't consider that disqualifying but views on that have gone back and forth over time.)

Comment: If data-prep (pre-compiling in a way) were regarded as separate step, the `|bc` example therefore wouldn't need to count those three bytes?

Comment: @agc: You aren't allowed to submit a program that requires multiple steps to run; you instead have to submit a program that automates those multiple steps. This is because the act of taking multiple steps contains information, which therefore counts against your score.